# Using recode() with variable names generated through paste()

Tags: r, paste, recode

I am trying to recode a variable which contains the labels of the answers as a character into numeric values. I am using `recode()` from dplyr for this.

To automate this I wanted to use `paste()` to generate the variable names but apparently `recode()` can't take the output from `paste`.

I already tried `noquote()` and `as.name()` but for both R tells me that recode can't use objects of the class "noquote"/"name".

Example:

```
item1 <- c("Don't agree at all", "Totally agree")
item2 <- c("Indifferent", "Totally agree")

for (i in 1:2) {
recode(paste("item", i, sep=""), "Totally agree"=1, "Indifferent"=2, "Don't agree at all"=3)
}
```

I would then expect

```
> item1
  [1] 3 1
```

How can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

I found a work around by first extracting the relevant columns into another dataframe and then applying the `recode()` function with `sapply()`. Now I can remerge the dataframes.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Small note: `paste0` will act just like `paste(a,b, sep="")`, i.e. pasting with no separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply could put a named vector `v` together with a list of your variables from `mget` into `Map` and subset it.

```
v <- c("Totally agree"=1, "Indifferent"=2, "Don't agree at all"=3)

Map(function(x, y) unname(y[x]), mget(ls(pattern="^item")), list(v))
# $item1
# [1] 3 1
# 
# $item2
# [1] 2 1
```

Or, suppose you have a data frame like this one,

```
head(dat1)
#   id         item1              item2         x
# 1  1 Totally agree      Totally agree 0.0356312
# 2  2 Totally agree      Totally agree 1.3149588
# 3  3 Totally agree        Indifferent 0.9781675
# 4  4 Totally agree        Indifferent 0.8817912
# 5  5   Indifferent        Indifferent 0.4822047
# 6  6   Indifferent Don't agree at all 0.9657529
```

then you may do this in a similar way. We may even simplify the code because we don't need the `Map` to return `unname`d objects anymore.

```
v1 <- c("Totally agree"=1, "Indifferent"=2, "Don't agree at all"=3)

item_nm <- c("item1", "item2")
dat1[item_nm] <- Map(`[`, list(v1), dat2[item_nm])
dat1
#    id item1 item2          x
# 1   1     1     1  0.0356312
# 2   2     1     1  1.3149588
# 3   3     1     2  0.9781675
# 4   4     1     2  0.8817912
# 5   5     2     2  0.4822047
# 6   6     2     3  0.9657529
# 7   7     2     3 -0.8145709
# 8   8     1     1  0.2839578
# 9   9     3     1 -0.1616986
# 10 10     3     3  1.9355718
```

The second argument gets recycled for each `Map` iteration (i.e. `list(v1, v1)` would also work).

And more generally, for each column you want to recode numerically, `list` one vector more in the second argument of `Map`.

```
head(dat2)
#   id         item1  item2         x
# 1  1 Totally agree Always 0.0356312
# 2  2 Totally agree Always 1.3149588
# 3  3 Totally agree   Both 0.9781675
# 4  4 Totally agree   Both 0.8817912
# 5  5   Indifferent   Both 0.4822047
# 6  6   Indifferent  Never 0.9657529

v2 <- c("Always"=1, "Both"=2, "Never"=3)

dat2[item_nm] <- Map(`[`, list(v1, v2), dat2[item_nm])
dat2
#    id item1 item2          x
# 1   1     1     1  0.0356312
# 2   2     1     1  1.3149588
# 3   3     1     2  0.9781675
# 4   4     1     2  0.8817912
# 5   5     2     2  0.4822047
# 6   6     2     3  0.9657529
# 7   7     2     3 -0.8145709
# 8   8     1     1  0.2839578
# 9   9     3     1 -0.1616986
# 10 10     3     3  1.9355718
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat1 <- structure(list(id = 1:10, item1 = c("Totally agree", "Totally agree", 
"Totally agree", "Totally agree", "Indifferent", "Indifferent", 
"Indifferent", "Totally agree", "Don't agree at all", "Don't agree at all"
), item2 = c("Totally agree", "Totally agree", "Indifferent", 
"Indifferent", "Indifferent", "Don't agree at all", "Don't agree at all", 
"Totally agree", "Totally agree", "Don't agree at all"), x = c(0.0356311982051355, 
1.31495884897891, 0.978167526364279, 0.881791226863203, 0.482204688262918, 
0.965752878105794, -0.814570938270238, 0.283957806364306, -0.161698647607024, 
1.93557176599585)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))

dat2 <- structure(list(id = 1:10, item1 = c("Totally agree", "Totally agree", 
"Totally agree", "Totally agree", "Indifferent", "Indifferent", 
"Indifferent", "Totally agree", "Don't agree at all", "Don't agree at all"
), item2 = c("Always", "Always", "Both", "Both", "Both", "Never", 
"Never", "Always", "Always", "Never"), x = c(0.0356311982051355, 
1.31495884897891, 0.978167526364279, 0.881791226863203, 0.482204688262918, 
0.965752878105794, -0.814570938270238, 0.283957806364306, -0.161698647607024, 
1.93557176599585)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to apply this to a data frame which contains the variables? 

So `df <- c(item1, item2)`

As it stands I would have to save each variable in an individual vector first right?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "but apparently recode() can't take the output from paste.": This has nothing to do with `recode` but (almost) **any** R function works this way. `paste` returns a string, and `recode` expects a vector as its first argument... (notable exception, amongst others: `library` where we can pass a string **or** the library name as an object).

What you could do, if you insist on the "for loop" approach is to use a combination of `assign` and something like `eval(sym("a string"))`:

```
item1 <- c("Don't agree at all", "Totally agree")
item2 <- c("Indifferent", "Totally agree")


library(dplyr)
for (i in 1:2) {
  assign(paste("item", i, sep="") , recode(eval(sym(paste("item", i, sep=""))), "Totally agree"=1, "Indifferent"=2, "Don't agree at all"=3))
}
```

That results in:

```
item1
```

> [1] 3 1

```
item2
```

> [1] 2 1

## Edit:

A probably more straightforward and a bit more "dplyr"-y approach would be something along the lines of:

```
tdd <- data.frame(item1, item2) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("item")), ~recode(., "Totally agree"=1, "Indifferent"=2, "Don't agree at all"=3))
```

And `tdd` is now:

```
tdd
```

> ```
>   item1 item2
> 1     3     2
> 2     1     1
> ```